# Codecoverage file creation using jenkins and CodeCoverage.exe

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage

I have used Codecoverage.exe of visual studio for creating the xml and the coverage file it is not creating the same.

> I am integrating the tool with jenkins.Any other way of doing it if possible

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the .coverage use the following command:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "PATH_OF_YOUR_EXECUTABLE_OR_DLL" /InIsolation /EnableCodeCoverage
```

Create a new command line project in Visual Studio and add a reference to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll
```

Then use the following code: (customize it as you want)

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis;

namespace CoverageConverter
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (CoverageInfo info = CoverageInfo.CreateFromFile(
            "PATH_OF_YOUR_*.coverage_FILE", 
            new string[] { @"DIRECTORY_OF_YOUR_DLL_OR_EXE"}, 
            new string[] { }))
        {
            CoverageDS data = info.BuildDataSet();
            data.WriteXml("converted.coveragexml");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Before executing your tool, you have to copy the following to the output directory of your project:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Symbols.dll
```

**The coverage is created according to a date-time and some random file name. It seems you can't change it according to the documentation. For that use a batch script to search and rename the .coverage file to a name you want.

Hope that helps !!

Comment: Thanks Anuja but i have to use command line like you have suggested at the first step of you solution but i have tried that and its giving a output coverage file but i want to use it in jenkins as a plugin or any thing that will change it to a html format

Comment: I want to use this as a plugin for jenkins.Can you tell any way for that

Comment: So get the .xml file and send it to ReportGenerator.exe and it will give you a HTML page. What's the problem?

Comment: but this reportgenerator.exe doesn't come as a plugin ti jenkins right?

Comment: Nope. You need to have a "Execute windows batch command" and call the cmd from there.